# Loop over Index Range

Tags: java, loops

Working in Java, I'm looking at a way to loop over a range of indices, based on a set number of entries that are needed per page. The use for this is to return specific elements that are on a specific page.

For instance, there are five elements per page, and I want all of the elements on page 5. If the starting index is 1 (not zero) then that means this method should iterate over indices 21-25.

How would i go about doing this?

(sorry for the lack of tags, i'm not sure what else this should be tagged with..)

Comment: Are you asking what the syntax of a for loop going from 21 to 25 is in Java?

Comment: Shouldn't you be employing basic mathematics?

Comment: Here's a [reference that explains for loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

Comment: @galuano1 Yes. BASIC mathematics. I was WAY overcomplicating it 6_9 Math isnt my strong suit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a little math in your code.  The product of the elements per page and the page number is the last index you want.  Then the start index is one past the ending index of the page before it.

```
int start = (page - 1) * (elementsPerPage) + 1;
int end = page * elementsPerPage;
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    // Your logic here
}
```

This was edited to show the calculations separately.

Comment: It would be nice to do the actual calcs _before_ the for loop (to make it readable)...

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. This worked. As i said in the comment above, i was trying to overcomplicate things, and it wasnt working. This worked flawlessly :] <3

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
for(int i = pageNumber*5-4; i <= pageNumber*5; i++)
{
  //access indices with i here
}
```